# How to listen for incoming calls Salesforce open cti?

Tags: webservices, opencti, softphone, call-center

we have a vendor where they don't have Salesforce Adaptor so we built custom adapter and  leveraged open cti javascript api to make outgoing calls it's working as expected

My concern is how do we automatically show a incoming call in Salesforce to a particular agent when recieved.

How to show a incoming call to only a particular agent or does Salesforce call center configuration automatically does this

or do we need to constantly check for server for new live incoming calls for every seconds

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.